# How to update stream.length of FirebaseFirestore data after record addition or deletion?

Tags: flutter, firebase, stream-builder

The code below displays list of records from FirebaseFirestore using AsyncSnapshot with StreamBuilder.  It works great, however I want to display the total number of records in the AppBar title and tht works when the app is launched, but doesn't update after any addition or deletion.

#### Question: How can I update the number of records (and display in Appbar title) after the list has an addition or deletion?

Note that I'm displaying the total number of records in the AppBar title using `title: Text('# Waiting: $numberWaiting'),`, but I can't figure out how to refresh this after the list changes.  **Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.**

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Query waitingList = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('waiting')
      .orderBy('Time_In');

  int numberWaiting = 0;   // Starts at 0; updated in StreamBuilder

  Future<void> delete(String docID) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('waiting').doc(docID).delete();
    // TODO: How to update numberWaiting in AppBar title?
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("# Waiting: ${numberWaiting.toString()}"),
      ),

      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: waitingList.snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Column(
                  ...
                );

              }

              else if (snapshot.hasData) {

                return ListView.builder (
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {

                    numberWaiting = index + 1;

                    String name = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['Name'];

                    return Card(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child:ListTile(

                          title:
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[

                                Text(name),

                              ],
                            ),

                          onTap: () {
                            // Create or Update Record
                            // TODO: Update numberWaiting for title
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
                              return CrudPage(
                                docId: snapshot.data?.docs[index].id.toString() ?? "",
                                docSnap: snapshot.data?.docs[index]);
                            }));
                          },

                          onLongPress: () {
                            // Delete Record
                            // TODO: Update numberWaiting for title
                            delete(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id.toString() ?? "");
                          },

                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }

              else {
                return const Text('No Data');
              }

            },  // Item Builder
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

#### Unfortunately this code only updates the `# Waiting: X` title once and doesn't refresh when an item is deleted or added.

#### Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#receiving-stream-events

Comment: @pskink Interesting page. Based on that, I tried ```Future<int> countStream(Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> stream) async => stream.length;```, but that just returns 'Future<int>' when put in a Text. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I found a way to do this, though I'm not convinced it's a great solution.  Basically, I added ```numberWaiting = (index + 1).toString();``` into the ```ListView.builder``` but above the start of the Card.  I'd love to know if anyone else has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply update value and rebuild  on "else if (snapshot.hasData)"
class HomePageState extends State {

```
  Query waitingList = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('waiting')
      .orderBy('Time_In');

  Future<int> countStream(Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> stream) async =>
      stream.length;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var numberWaiting = "";

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("# Waiting: $numberWaiting"),
      ),

      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: waitingList.snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Column(
                  ...
                );

              }

              else if (snapshot.hasData) {

                setState((){
numberWaiting = snapshot.data?.docs.length.toString();
})
                return ListView.builder (
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {

                    String name = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['Name'];

                    return Card(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child:ListTile(

                          title:
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[

                                Text(name),

                              ],
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }

              else {
                return const Text('No Data');
              }

            },  // Item Builder
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see what you trying to do, however, this code gives me this ERROR:
```
setState() called during build.
This HomePage widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the fragment is already in the process of building widgets...
The widget was currently being built when the offending call was made: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
```

Comment: Could I wrap the Scaffold Title in a FutureBuilder?

Comment: Not really the best approach but it is very okey to wrap the Whole Scaffold with the StreamBuilder and exploit your options.